# How to check last line of file for new_line character? C++

Tags: c++, file, newline, eof, getline

How can I check if the lastline in a file contains a '\n' (or newline).

Here are two examples:
[a file with newline at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf3U4.png) -
[a file without newline at the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTnoO.png)

My current code:

```
fstream file("filename");
string line;
if (!file.is_open()) throw Exception();
while(getline(file, line))
{
    (checking for lastline)
}
```

I realized that getline won't contain the new_line character. I could go through each character, but there would be a performance problem. There are files with millions of characters and I don't know how to go to the end line to get the new_line character.

--- **EDIT** ---

- Maybe I forgot to mention that my enviroment is UNIX only. So I will
  only use the end_line character '\n'.
- Secondly, I need getline to check each line for some errors (but its not relevant here).
- I will check my lastline before the while loop so I can sip it, if the file is invalid!
- My images shows CR LF which is my bad. sry for the mistake. There should be only LF.

Comment: How about, seek to the end? Note that seeking is generelly very UB for text mode so do that in binary mode, or check details of how it's supported or not.

Comment: *"'\n' (or newline)"* sounds like a very imprecise requirement. What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [seekg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to jump to any position in the file.

```
file.seekg(-1,ios_base::end);    // go to one position before the EOF
char c;
file.get(c);                     // Read current character
if(c=='\n'){
    cout<<"yes"<<endl;           // You have new_line character
}
```

So we jump to one position before the EOF and read the last character. If it is a new line, you are done.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different methods to indicate the new line.

- Two characters CR LF (\r\n): DOS, OS/2, Microsoft Windows, Symbian, DEC RT-1 1
- One character CR (\r): Commodore, Apple II, Mac OS (until version 9), Microware OS-9
- One character LF (\n): Unix, BeOS, AmigaOS, MorphOS, RISC OS, GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Multics

Dont use getline(), it will eat new line character. Use read() in binary mode (see Cheers and hth. - Alf comment). Text mode will replace every new line tag CR LF, and CR to LF. In your example you have CR LF tag.

In binary mode you have to go to one or two characters minus file length and then read() two characters, then check they are equal to CR LF. See Rishit example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with getline is that it reads lines and puts them into a std::string, but strips new line characters. What you will need is to use binary mode reading functions. The most difficult task is to make it find all possible new lines combinations and also work with various file sizes, and finally make it look elegant. Below is my try at how to do it.

The question is if for example your platform stores new line as '\r\n' then if \n or \r, also counts as new line on last line?

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06f70dd4ef5c63c8

```
    std::ofstream ofs("test.txt");
    ofs << "test \n" << "test 2\n";
    //ofs << "\r";
    ofs.close();

    std::ifstream ifs("test.txt", std::ifstream::binary);

    // Read last two chars, it might also read only one last char
    std::vector<char> end_file_chars;
    for (int pos = 1; pos <= 2; ++pos) {
        if (!ifs.seekg(-pos, std::ios::end)) break;
        char c;
        if (ifs.get(c)) end_file_chars.insert(end_file_chars.begin(), c);
    }

    // Possible end file characters
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> endlines = {{'\r', '\n'},
                                               {'\n'},
                                               {'\r'}};

    // Predicate to compare possible endline with what was found in the file.
    auto checkFn = [&](auto &endline) {
        // Equal compares possible endline in reverse order
        return std::equal(endline.rbegin(), endline.rend(), end_file_chars.rbegin());
    };

    // If any end file character was read and if it acually is end file character...
    if (!end_file_chars.empty() && std::find_if(endlines.begin(), endlines.end(),checkFn) != endlines.end()) {
        std::cout << "Found";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Not Found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
fgets(string_name, buffer_size, stdin)
```

fgets() includes the new_line character unlike gets() and 
fputs() excludes the new_line character unlike puts()

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Example:

```
while( fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) ) {
    // check newline at end of string
    int len = strlen(str);

    if( str[ len-1 ] != '\0' ) {
        str[ len-1 ] = '\0'; // make sure there's no new_line at the end
        len--;
    }

    // now check for empty string, if thus, then last line
    if( strcmp(str, "") == 0 ) break;
}
```

Comment: What if line is longer than buffer?

Comment: Then rest of the characters will be in buffer, and it will take input until buffer is not cleared.

Comment: Got your point. It will left the rest of the characters in buffer, but replace the last character in str with '\0'!!!

Comment: Is `if( str[ len-1 ] != '\0' )` supposed to be `if( str[ len-1 ] == '\n' )`?  (Because strlen would set len to the index of the first nul in str, so the only way I could see this detecting a nul at index len-1 would be if str was zero-length (len is zero) and because this condition is not checked for, a spurious nul could happen to exist before the start of the string, at index -1, but this is not intended, certainly).